# Getting PHP Error 500 with Apache on Ubuntu from a composer project

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, composer-php

I am facing an error for days now and I really can't figure out what it is. I have a local composer project downloaded from BitBucket, where I need an Apache Server and PHP. I installed PHP, MySQL as well as Apache as well as composer but after installing the project with `composer install` and running `localhost` on port 80 as well as 8080 with
 `php -S localhost:8080 -t public public/index.php`

I get this error `PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/../src/config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/michael/userlane-controlcenter/public/index.php on line 12`

I checked whether the files are there but everything seems to be alright. I tried this process as a normal user and as root but this didn't help me either.

Furthermore I have already added the localhost to the servername.conf file

Comment: Did you do a `composer dumpautoload`? seems like maybe there's some cache issue.

Comment: No the only command I executued with composer was `composer install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you dont use root folder for site. Change project to root and check again

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution it was a error in the index.php file, which I simply corrected.